# Python Tensorflow-GPU: Install

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, conda

I have installed Tensorflow for GPU using Anaconda, with the following command:

```
conda install tensorflow-gpu
```

I have run into a strange error while trying to work with this environment, and while researching potential causes I found out that most others use the seemingly more traditional way of installing cuda, then cuDNN etc.

The reason I even installed tensorflow like this is because installing cuda always failed at the last step, without telling me why. Thats why the traditional approach won't work for me, and I need a work-around.

My question: is the method of installing TensorFlow for GPU as shown above a decent way to do it, or has it known errors? Would you recommend me to use the 'traditional' approach?

Comment: Before executing `conda install tensorflow-gpu` you should first install software requirements mentioned in https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu . Since you have already tried and failed I think it might be a good idea to uninstall existing versions.

Comment: _I have run into a strange error_ What error? _The reason I even installed tensorflow like this is because installing cuda always failed at the last step, without telling me why._ I'm confused, is one an alternative to the other? _Thats why the traditional approach won't work for me, and I need a work-around._ Are you sure that there is no other solution to the CUDA installation problem? Can you share some more information on the subject? _is the method of installing TensorFlow for GPU as shown above a decent way to do it, or has it known errors?_ I'm sure there are known bugs/issues.

Comment: _Would you recommend me to use the 'traditional' approach?_ I thought you didn't have a choice?

Comment: @AMC _What Error?_ Well, it isn't really an Error, because compiling the code works fine, however, the PyCharm console prints something along the line of "Successfully entered dynamic library cudart64.dll" in red. It doesn't sound like an error, but only error messages are printed in red, therefore am I confused. **Next:** It It seems like using `conda install tensorflow-gpu` installs cuda and cuDNN for you, as it is listed when I use `conda list`. On the other hand, cuda is not listed in my "programs and features" Windows tab. That's what I am confused about, is it really installed or not?

Comment: @AMC _Are you sure there are no other solutions?_ That's what I am asking; I am looking for these other solutions, as installing cuda manually (for some reason) fails. _I am sure there are known bugs._ That's not what I'm talking about, I mean: is it a legitimate and complete way of installing TensorFlow for GPU, or does it need more to work? _I thought you didnt have a choice?_ Currently, I don't think I have, but if only the "traditional" way will truly work, then I guess I just have to dig deeper into it.